# Проблема с переносом приложения из Qt Designer в PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlayout

Такая проблема: Делаю дизайн приложения в *Qt Design* и все получается супер классно, а потом после конвертации **`.ui`** в файл **`.py`** и запуска приложения в редакторе кода, все съезжает.

Как это решить?

[image: скрин из qt design]

[image: скрин из pycharm]

Comment: Опубликуйте ваш модуль `.ui`.  Покажите что вы делаете для конвертации  `.ui` в  `.py`. Опубликуйте полученный модуль `.py`, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Для конвертации использую команду "pyuic5 -x fistq.ui -o firstq.py". [https://github.com/NikolyaiTimoshenko/stuck]

Answer (score 1):

У меня наш код никуда не съезжает. Видимо на вашей машине и в Qt Designer используются разные стили.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Научитесь использовать менеджеры компоновки: [**Layout Management**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)

Using [**Layouts in Qt Designer**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html)

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**fistq2.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>500</width>
    <height>400</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.220639, y1:0.766636, x2:0.861136, y2:0.0795455, stop:0 rgba(62, 155, 240, 255), stop:1 rgba(13, 10, 255, 255));
</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <spacer name="verticalSpacer_2">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>20</width>
        <height>60</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="namefill_3">
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>28</pointsize>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>ВОПРОС</string>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <spacer name="verticalSpacer_3">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>20</width>
        <height>15</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item alignment="Qt::AlignHCenter">
     <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Первый ответ на первый вопрос</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <spacer name="verticalSpacer_4">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>20</width>
        <height>25</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item alignment="Qt::AlignHCenter">
     <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton_2">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Второй ответ на первый вопрос</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <spacer name="verticalSpacer_5">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>20</width>
        <height>25</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item alignment="Qt::AlignHCenter">
     <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton_3">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Третий ответ на первый вопрос</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>20</width>
        <height>90</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**firstq2.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(500, 400)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.220639, y1:0.766636, x2:0.861136, y2:0.0795455, stop:0 rgba(62, 155, 240, 255), stop:1 rgba(13, 10, 255, 255));\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 60, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.namefill_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.namefill_3.setFont(font)
        self.namefill_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);")
        self.namefill_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.namefill_3.setObjectName("namefill_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.namefill_3)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 15, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.radioButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.radioButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.radioButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 25, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem2)
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.radioButton_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.radioButton_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.radioButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_2, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 25, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem3)
        self.radioButton_3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.radioButton_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.radioButton_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.radioButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_3, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        spacerItem4 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 90, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem4)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.namefill_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Первый ответ на первый вопрос"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Второй ответ на первый вопрос"))
        self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Третий ответ на первый вопрос"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        # !!!
        # !!! тут ваша логика
        # !!!
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Nikolay что не так?